# Error whenever search bar and search display controller is pressed

Tags: xcode5, searchbar

Okay so i started from a tab controller and it's a travel app, but the search bar is not able to be typed in when clicked it crashes with this error and i checked google and nothing came up.

```
[2014-08-01 11:08:49.371 challenger\[13968:60b\] -\[UIViewControllertableView:numberOfRowsInSection:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e3aee0
2014-08-01 11:08:49.417 challenger\[13968:60b\] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-\[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e3aee0']
```

Comment: i have a picture but i can't post it because not enough reputation so sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the UISearchDisplayController is overlaying it's own table view, therefore it needs its own data source, depending on the search results it displays.

In the methods numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSections, test which table view is displayed, then return either the number of standard sections and rows, or those of the search display controller. Likewise, when you return the table view cell make sure you either return a standard cell or a search result cell. If either section or cell is nil the table view returns your error.

I have a demo project on GitHub that shows how this works: https://github.com/versluis/TableSearch2014

Comment: I am new to all of this Xcode so what your saying is it can't work because there is no slide after?

Comment: Examine the demo project, it shows how the search display controller is implemented. I have no idea what you mean by "slide after" I'm afraid.

Comment: this is solved Thanks it seemed to be there was no delegate or refrencing outlets